# Anyone knows how to increase the size of the console icon in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have increase the size of fonts but the icon on the top console still very very little. How can I change it to be bigger?

I have attach photo here it is:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On windows it would be **File --> Settings --> Editor --> Colors & Fonts** then save as, name it something then you can edit all the fields you want.

on Mac  **Preferences --> Editor --> Colors & Fonts, in the right side,** then click "**save as**...", this will create a new Scheme, we name it such as "Custom", then all fields become to editable, font, space, color, etc.

Comment: I didn't mean color and fonts I mean the icon button. Font size are ok for me right now but the icon button like save, open, cut, undo, redo and the text on the left bar are too small.